# Angular: Set The Hidden Value of Select Statement to Always be Text

Tags: javascript, html, angular, select

I currently have a drop down that functions as normal meaning when you select a statement the top part of the dropdown (the part that shows even when the dropdown has not been clicked) shows the last clicked symbol. Is there a way I can make it so that part of the dropdown always says the word 'Symbols' instead so it is obvious what that specific dropdown does before someone clicks it?

[image]

So in the picture above you can see the first option in the select is equivales and thus that shows at the top that is highlighted in blue. And if I choose a new option the top part will change to that. But is there a way so the top part can always be a static phrase like 'Symbols' regardless of the currently selected option? Here is my code:

```html
<select
            id="symbolInLineSelector"
            (change)="insertSymbol($event.target.value)"
            class="ql-size"
            title="symbolSelect">
            <option
              *ngFor="let symbol of keys(symbols)"
              [ngValue]="symbol"
              [innerHtml]="symbols[symbol]">
            </option>
</select>
```

Here is my ts:

```js
insertSymbol(selectedVal) {
    this.editorInstance.insertText(this.previousEditorSelection, selectedVal.value.substring(0, selectedVal.value.length - 15));
    this.editorInstance.setSelection(this.previousEditorSelection.index + selectedVal.value.length + 2);
    this.previousEditorSelection = this.editorInstance.getSelection();
    selectedVal.value = -1;
  }
```

Comment: You can add the placeholder attribute to select tag some thing like placeholder="Symbols"

Comment: it isnt finding placeholder

Comment: Can you share it in plunker

Answer (score 0):

You can add a static option that is "symbols" and handle that value in your change function

in ts:

```
    insertSymbol(select:any){
     //set your value as appropriate: 
        myValue = select.value;
     //set selector to the default -1:
        select.value = -1;
     }
```

```html
<select
            id="symbolInLineSelector"
            (change)="insertSymbol($event.target)"
            class="ql-size"
            title="symbolSelect">
<option value="-1">Symbols</option>
            <option
              *ngFor="let symbol of keys(symbols)"
              [ngValue]="symbol"
              [innerHtml]="symbols[symbol]">
            </option>
</select>
```

Comment: What would the code be in the typescript to always change the selected option to Symbols?

Comment: Pass event.target instead of event.target.value.  Once you have inserted your symbol as appropriate, set event.target.value =-1

Comment: It still updates the top part with what I just clicked

Comment: I added my typescript above, it only works if I put the selectedVal.value = -1 as the first call in my method and if I do that nothing inputs into my editor on click

Comment: Did you update your html to also have the first option tag like my example?  You still only have the option tag with the ngFor loop.